# Efficient way of spliting, applying function and returning data.frame with variable vector length

Tags: r, plyr, processing-efficiency

I am currently trying to use `plyr` + `reshape2` to proccess my data, but it is taking a lot of time.
I have a dataframe (*df*) with 3 columns: **network**, **user_id** and **date**.
My goal is:

1. To split *df* in 2 levels (**network** and **user_id**);
2. apply a function (`get_interval`) in each split;
3. bind the results in another dataframe (*df2*).

`get_interval` returns a vector of the same length as the number of rows of the input. 
Thus, *df2* has the same size of *df*, but with the results computed by `get_interval`.

The problem is that I cannot use `ddply` directly, since it only handles vectors of equal length and the results of the function have varied length.

I came up with this solution:

```
aux <- melt(dlply(df,.(network,user_id), get_interval))
df2 <- cbind(interval=aux$value,colsplit(aux$L1,"\\.",names=c("network","user_id")))
```

But it is very inefficient, and since *df* is quite big I waste hours every time I have to run it.
Is there a way of doing this more efficiently?

### **EDIT**

The basic operation of `get_interval` is as follows:

```
get_interval <- function(df){
    if(nrow(df) < 2)
        return (NA)
    x <- c(NA,df$date[-1] - df$date[-nrow(df)])
    return(x) ## ceiling wont work because some intervals are 0.
}
```

It is possible to generate this data artificially with:

```
n <- 1000000
ref_time <- as.POSIXct("2013-12-17 00:00:00")
interval_range <- 86400*10 # 10 days
df <- data.frame(user_id=floor(runif(n,1,n/10)),
                network=gl(2,n,labels=c("anet","unet")),
                value=as.POSIXct(ref_time - runif(n,0,interval_range)))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. If your data is too big, provide us with a code that'll generate a dummy data of your dimensions and the total number of groups you've (in splitting by *network* and *user_id*. Give us some idea about your function `foo` so that it's easy to tell if your bottleneck is your function.